# 32 bits in single ROM address in Logisim Evolution

Tags: circuit, rom

I need to store a lot of data (32bits * 255) in Logisim Evolution. I want to use the ROM component, so that it is relatively easy to import data. When I put it together, I set Address Width to 8 and Data Width to 32. I expected each address to be 32 bits, but it seems that each address holds 8. Is there a setting I'm missing? Or should I use a different component?
**Edit:** I'm a dummy. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize that it is stored as hexadecimal. I thought it was binary. It is four hexadecimal places, so 32 bits.